# VSCODE doesn't recognize subclassing of db.Model

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, flask-sqlalchemy, pylance, intellicode

I have a Flask Project with Flask-SQLAlchemy and a custom Model class.

For type hinting I modified the SQLAlchemy class like this:

```
class CustomSQLAlchemy(flask_sqlalchemy.SQLAlchemy):
    Model: CustomModel
```

After that, VSCODE does show db.Model as a CustomModel:

[image: Subclass of db.Model]
[image: Subclass of db.Model]

However, when adding attributes I don't get any suggestions for attributes from db.Model when using super for instance. I think it has something to do with the fact that db.Model isn't hinted as a class like ToolTimeMixIn. I know I can use db.Model instead of super(), but I personally find it inconvenient.

I am using Pylance and Visual Studio IntelliCode with a Python 3.9 venv.
I know it is unlikely, but does someone have experience with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research I have found the solution:

```
from typing import Type

class CustomSQLAlchemy(flask_sqlalchemy.SQLAlchemy):
    Model: Type[CustomModel]
    Query: Type[CustomQueryObject]


db = CustomSQLAlchemy(query_class=CustomQueryObject, model_class=CustomModel, session_options={"expire_on_commit": False})
```

With this VSCODE will recognize db.Model as a class and give proper suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I found these while organizing my note. They are my current solution and I hope they can help

- [ssfdust/flask-sqlalchemy-stubs](https://github.com/ssfdust/flask-sqlalchemy-stubs) better typed stubs.
- a working stubs [ryanwang520/flask_sqlalchemy-s tubs](https://github.com/ryanwang520/flask_sqlalchemy-stubs/tree/master/flask_sqlalchemy-stubs). It's quality is not as good as the `ssfdust` above, but it helps pylance to understand the code.
- To enable stubs in VSCode (pylance), create a `typings` folder in the root of your project, and put the stubs in it like this instruction in [pylance-release#187](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/187#issuecomment-666609497). Or, to use a custom folder, see [pylance-release#285](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/285)
- Note all stubs are for flask-sql-alchemy based on sql-alchemy 1.4.0, which is subject to update as the new version of sql-alchemy release candidates rc2 are out.